# Road network analysis

Tags: point, distance, network-analyst

I have a road layer and point features of some bus stops from the same area.  I want to find the road distance between the bus stops. Please help me find it.

I have QGIS, ArcGIS, and FME.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Could you please explain your question detail with screen shot(Road distance between two bus stop or anything different in your mind)..thanks

Comment: Hi Sunil, I have two shapfiles line and POIs(Road and Bus stops),I know it is possible to get the length of lines and the Distance between two Points,when we are find it as individual layers.Here,I want to open two shapefiles in a window(road and bus stop) and get the distance between the two bus stops(not air distance,but Road distance).

Thanks,
RKM

Answer (score 1):

FME: NeighborFinder input roads and points return  _distance value which is points distance to closest line.

If you want to find how long route is between stops then use FME's ShortestPathFinder

Comment: Based on these descriptions, NeighborFinder does not answer the question but ShortestPathFinder does.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Road Graph plugin in QGIS, URL: http://gis-lab.info/qa/road-graph-eng.html